# Is getURL deprecated?

Tags: r, rcurl

I booted up a shiny application today only to see that my program could no longer access USGS water data. This program has been working so I assumed there was an update on the data source, but no such thing had happened. I updated all my packages and am wondering if anyone can shine some insight into what has happened, my first thought being something may have depreciated.

```
library(RCurl)
library(utils)

#Url For Water Data Download
url<-'https://waterdata.usgs.gov/mt/nwis/uv/?cb_00060=on&format=rdb&site_no=06037500&period=&begin_date=2019-02-12&end_date=2019-02-12'

#Download Data
urlcontent<- getURL(url)
```

This code simply begins the process of downloading data froma  USGS site, today it gives me the error

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

To thicken the plot I have a currently deployed version of this application running on shiny.io which can still access the data just fine.

Comment: It may have something to do with the TLS protocol, as discussed in the referenced question above. `getURL` seems to work for other sites, Stackoverflow.com for instance.

Comment: @Mako212 Thanks for the info I will look into it, just strange that it was working yesterday and not today since those protocols seemed to be an issue ~3 years ago.

Comment: You could use `httr:GET(url)` instead.

Comment: @Mako212 using the curl library seemed to work, guess I was using some old functions to get my data, needed an update anyway. Thank you for the help.